# Computing $\det(a_1 M_{ij} + a_2 b_i b_j + a_3 c_i c_j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

I found interesting formula which seems hard to prove.

> Let $M=(M_{ij})$ be an invertible $d\times d$ symmetric matrix. Then
> \begin{align}
> \det(a_1 M_{ij} + a_2 b_i b_j + a_3 c_i c_j) 
> = a_1^{d-2} \det(M_{ij}) \left( (a_1 + a_2 b^2)(a_1 + a_3 c^2) - a_2 a_3 (b\cdot c)^2 \right)
> \end{align}
> where
> \begin{align}
> b^2 = b_i b_j (M^{-1})^{ij}, \quad c^2 = c_i c_j (M^{-1})^{ij}, \quad b\cdot c = b_i c_j (M^{-1})^{ij}
> \end{align}
> and $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_1 \neq 0$, $b_i, c_i$ are arbitrary $d$-column vectors.

For $a_2=a_3=0$ it reduce $\det(a M_{ij}) = a^d \det(M_{ij})$ so it seems fine. and for $a_2=0$ or $a_3=0$ seems fine.

\begin{align}
\det(a_1 M_{ij} + a_2 b_i b_j) &=  \det\left( a_1 M_{ij} (Id + a_1^{-1}a_2 M^{ij}  b_i b_j) \right)  \\
&
=\det(a_1 M_{ij}) (1+\operatorname{tr}(a_1^{-1} a_2 (M^{-1})^{ij} b_i b_j)  \\
&= a_1^{d-2} \det(M_{ij}) \left( a_1^{2} + a_1 a_2 b^2\right)
\end{align}
In the process I used  "for the rank one matrix $A$, $\det(Id+A) = 1+\operatorname{tr}(A)$"

So for $a_2=0$ or $a_3=0$ is fine, but I am having trouble for $a_2 \neq 0, a_3 \neq 0$. Is there any nice approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking at is a double bordered determinant, the determinant of a matrix of this sort
$$
H:=
\begin{pmatrix}
A & K\\
L^{T} & B
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is $d\times d$, $K,L$ are $d\times 2$, and $B$ is $2\times 2$. We assume that $A,B$ are invertible.

We can find two expressions for $\det H$ by factorising $H$ in the following ways:
$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
A& O\\O&I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I& O\\L^{T} & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I & A^{-1}K\\O &B-L^{T}A^{-1}K
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
I& O\\O&B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I& K\\O & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A-KB^{-1}L^{T} & O\\B^{-1}L^{T} & I
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

We will then have
$$
\det H = \det A\ \det(B-L^{T}A^{-1}K)=\det B\ \det(A-KB^{-1}L^{T}).
$$

So now let $A=a_1 M$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}a_2 & 0\\0& a_3\end{pmatrix}$, $K=\begin{pmatrix} b & c \end{pmatrix}$, and $L=\begin{pmatrix}  -b & -c \end{pmatrix}$. The two expressions for the determinant are the two expressions you wish to equate.